# Android Lollipop transition specific views in Activity Enter

Tags: android, android-transitions

I am trying to implement the new Transitions API in my application and I am stuck with a specific problem.

In my activity I want to do an enter Slide transition on specific views. Here is my layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.github.ksoichiro.android.observablescrollview.ObservableScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="180dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivRestaurantBg"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/background_poly" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="70dp">

                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/cvRestaurantLogo"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:transitionName="sharedRestaurantLogo"
                    android:src="@drawable/placeholder" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/cvRestaurantLogo"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cvRestaurantLogo"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvRestaurantName"
                        style="@style/HeaderText"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvRestaurantAddress"
                        style="@style/HeaderText"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvRestaurantContactNo"
                        style="@style/HeaderText"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </FrameLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/anchor"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:minHeight="180dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/body"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/anchor"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

            <include android:id="@+id/mapSegment" layout="@layout/card_map_lite" /> <!-- Layout 1 to transition -->

            <include android:id="@+id/customerSegment" layout="@layout/card_customer_details" /> <!-- Layout 2 to transition -->

           <include android:id="@+id/ordersSegment" layout="@layout/card_dish_details" /> <!-- Layout 3 to transition -->

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/accept_order"
                android:id="@+id/btnAcceptOrder"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/green_button"
                android:minWidth="120dp"
                android:minHeight="50dp"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</com.github.ksoichiro.android.observablescrollview.ObservableScrollView>

<include layout="@layout/gradient_header" />

<include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

</FrameLayout>
```

And in my activity I do this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTIVITY_TRANSITIONS);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);

    Transition transition = TransitionInflater.from(this)
            .inflateTransition(R.transition.shared_element_transition);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_order_details);
    mMapSegment = findViewById(R.id.mapSegment);
    mCustomerSegment = findViewById(R.id.customerSegment);
    mOrdersSegment = findViewById(R.id.orderSegment);

    TransitionSet set = new TransitionSet();

    Slide mapSlide = new Slide();
    mapSlide.setDuration(2000);
    mapSlide.setSlideEdge(Gravity.BOTTOM);
    mapSlide.addTarget(mMapSegment);

    //others ignored

    set.addTransition(mapSlide);

    getWindow().setEnterTransition(set);
    getWindow().setSharedElementEnterTransition(transition);
}
```

However this does not seem to work. The shared element transition works as expected but not the enter transition. If I remove the `slide.addTarget(mMapSegment)` line, I can see the whole activity's views get animated so I am pretty sure it has something to do with adding specific targets to the Transition. Am I doing something wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I know this was asked a while ago, but I just had the same issue happen to me again so I thought I would share what worked for me.  I wrapped the view I was trying to slide in a new LinearLayout (match_parent/match_parent).  I do not know why this (normally useless) viewGroup allowed the addTarget to start working, but this has helped me more than a few times now.

To narrow down the issue to addTarget, I normally replace my target with addTarget(View.class).  If you see the entire screen transition, then it's an addTarget issue.  Otherwise something else is likely not wired up correctly.

The other thing that I sometimes have to do is android:transitionGroup="false" to the parent viewGroup of the new LinearLayout that I added.  Why this is need sometimes and not others, I don't fully understand.

Hope this helps those working on activity transitions.

Comment: Thanks @scott, I ended up implementing ObjectAnimator on the views to achieve the expected output. Hope this answer helps someone working on transitions